# Writing an undefined variable as a variable to a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, variables, dictionary

I am trying in one file to write a dictionary that will be written and used in a second file.

file1 holds a config setting

```
bar = 'name'
```

file2 writes to the config

```
foo = {}
foo['user'] = bar
with open('file1', 'a') as f:
    f.write("foo = %s" % foo)
```

What I would like the outcome to be.

file1

```
bar = 'name'
foo = {'user': bar}
```

As written now I'm getting a KeyError in file2 because 'bar' is not defined.  I don't want to define 'bar' in file2 because it is defined in file1. I want to write 'bar' as the variable 'bar' itself not the value that 'bar' holds.
Is there any way around this?

Comment: [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: you could do foo['user']=None or foo['user'] = foo.get('user',None) as a placeholder in file1

Comment: Can you expand your code example to provide a [mcve]?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You're not showing us what `file1` is, and we're left to guess where the KeyError is.

Comment: Hopefully this update will clear it up a bit

Comment: Perhaps in file2, you want "from file1 import bar, foo"

Comment: That's actually how I solved it. 

I imported file1, edited foo in file2 then wrote it back to file1.